# npm i -g vue-cli is not installing vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am running on powershell or in gitbash
`npm i -g vue-cli,`

so after running, I got these warning

`npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-core@3.11.1: The` apollo-server-core`package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the`@apollo/server `package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.`

`changed 853 packages in 37s

64 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details`

So I believe its already installed though the warning is like that.

So when I do `vue --version`, it gives me this error message

`vue : The term 'vue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- vue --version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
  ```

weird, right? Can you please suggest what I should do next? Or how to fix this?

suggestions and can explain if what is behind this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you installed have been deprecated, as explained here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli

Check the new one

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

So, if you really want to use Vue CLI, you need to run the following

```
npm install -g @vue/cli

# OR

yarn global add @vue/cli
```

But, please, note the following (from https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/)

> ⚠️ Vue CLI is in Maintenance Mode!
>
> For new projects, it is now recommended to use create-vue to scaffold
> Vite-based projects. Also refer to the Vue 3 Tooling Guide for the
> latest recommendations.

So, for new projects, you should opt for the new package instead

https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue

Comment: Thanks, this information helps me a lot https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/ to realize what's the issues

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```bash
npm install -g @vue/cli
```